# How to reuse methods?

Tags: java, function, methods, delegates

I am a beginner and i try to teach myself clean coding. I want to pass a function as a parameter that I can reuse a method without to repeat code. As an example I have this:

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<String> characteristic;

    public List<String> getCharacteristic() {
        return characteristic;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic(List<String> characteristic) {
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }
 }

public class Check{
    private List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList();

    public void iterate() {
        while (dogs.size() > 0) {
            for (Dog dog : dogs) {
                List<String> restChara = new ArrayList<>();
                restChara= checkChara(dog, restChara);
                if (restChara.size()>0) {
                    dog.setCharacteristic(restChara);
                } else {
                    dogs.remove(dog);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<String> checkChara(Dog dog, List<String> restChara) {
        for (String chara : dog.getCharacteristic()) {
            boolean charaChecked = doSomething(chara);
            if (!charaChecked) {
                restChara.add(chara);
            } else {
                dog.getCharacteristic().remove(chara);
            }
        }
        return restChara;
    }

    private boolean doSomething(String chara){
        //do sth.
        return true;
    }
    private boolean doSomething2(String chara){
        //do sth.
        return true;
    }
}
```

How would you define the method checkChara in order to use different functions within it?

My first thought was to pass the function as a parameter (i think it would be in C# delegates)

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

I think I found another pattern strategy design pattern

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-strategy-pattern-explained-using-java-bc30542204e0/

Comment: you reuse methods by calling them from seperate places in your code, how else?

Comment: ok, that wasn't clearly expressed, sorry.

Comment: You asking about Java lambdas? Or what?

Comment: yes Lambdas or interfaces,I dont know how to achieve that in most easy way

Answer (score 0):

I don't exaclty know what you mean, but i figure out it could be something like that:

```
List<Runnable> runMyStuff = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        String variable= "Hallo"; //needs to be effectively final 
        runMyStuff.add(() -> {
            System.out.println(variable);
            doSomething(variable);

        });

        runMyStuff.add(() ->{
            System.out.println("This is a test");
        });

        runMyStuff.add(() ->{
            System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + (2+2) );
        });

        runMyStuff.get(0).run();
        runMyStuff.get(2).run();
        runMyStuff.get(0).run();
        runMyStuff.get(1).run();
        runMyStuff.get(2).run();
```

will result in :

```
Hallo
2 + 2 = 4
Hallo
This is a test
2 + 2 = 4
```

When you put variables or Passing Parameters in those runnable methods, they need to be effectively final or you pass them in a container.
You can re-run each method.
And within those Methods you can execute other methods.

**NOTE**:
If you want to have return Parameters you could do the same with Callable and than ".call()" instead of run.

**EDIT**:
Under the assumption you mean character Check or something like that
Example for charaCheck passable Method With Interface:

```
    public interface CharacterChecker{
        //is a template returns boolean, need a String param
        public boolean call(String chara);

    }
```

A method that executes a passes method of the type of "CHaracterChecker"

```
public static void excecutePassedMethod(CharacterChecker checker, String chara) {
        System.out.println(chara + ": " + checker.call(chara));
    }
```

Two different implementations of a "Character Checker"

```
        CharacterChecker goodChecker = new CharacterChecker() {

            @Override
            public boolean call(String chara) {
                return "good".equals(chara);

            }
        };

        CharacterChecker lazyCheker = new CharacterChecker() {

            @Override
            public boolean call(String chara) {
                return "lazy".equals(chara);

            }
        };
```

The Methods that are Passed the "method" (More like anonymos class object with the method)

```
        excecutePassedMethod(goodChecker, "bad");
        excecutePassedMethod(goodChecker, "good");
        excecutePassedMethod(goodChecker, "jolly");

        excecutePassedMethod(lazyCheker, "frisky");
        excecutePassedMethod(lazyCheker, "lazy");
```

result will be:

```
bad: false
good: true
jolly: false
frisky: false
lazy: true
```

Comment: This would work but I could also simply add a switch case to the method and pass an int so that a certain method is executed. 
But I want other developers to be able to just call the method and pass a function as a parameter

Comment: @Kleinstein11 what do you mean with "other developers pass a function" ? 
I would recommend using Interfaces then. Probably. 
Also they could add a own runnable method to the list, and run them later. You could also use a map or something like that.
But i would not recomment passing functions in that Manner. It's Better to use Interfaces.

Comment: could you show me an example of how to solve the above problem with interfaces? 

i've never really understood this thing xD

Comment: @Kleinstein11
I would recommend looking deeper into Interfaces because this is really usefull and important, for "templating" certain types of Objects.
In your case you want to have a different "doSomething" in CheckChara.

But you want only a return value ot the Type boolean. So you could Use a "Callable<Boolean>" that could be passed into the "CheckChara".

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support “directly” nested methods. Many functional programming languages support method within method. But you can achieve nested method functionality in Java 7 or older version by define local classes, class within method so this does compile. And in java 8 and newer version you achieve it by lambda expression.

**Method 1 (Using anonymous subclasses)**

It is an inner class without a name and for which only a single object is created. An anonymous inner class can be useful when making an instance of an object with certain “extras” such as overloading methods of a class or interface, without having to actually subclass a class.

```
//Java program implements method inside method 
public class GFG { 

// create a local interface with one abstract 
// method run() 
interface myInterface { 
    void run(); 
} 

// function have implements another function run() 
static void Foo() 
{ 
    // implement run method inside Foo() function 
    myInterface r = new myInterface() { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            System.out.println("geeksforgeeks"); 
        }; 
    }; 
    r.run(); 
} 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Foo(); 
} 
}
```

**Method 2 (Using local classes)**
You can also implement a method inside a local class. A class created inside a method is called local inner class. If you want to invoke the methods of local inner class, you must instantiate this class inside method.

```
// Java program implements method inside method 
public class GFG { 

// function have implementation of another  
// function inside local class 
static void Foo() 
{ 
    // local class 
    class Local { 
        void fun() 
        { 
            System.out.println("geeksforgeeks"); 
        } 
    } 
    new Local().fun(); 
} 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Foo(); 
} 
}
```

**Method 3 (Using a lambda expression)**
Lambda expressions basically express instances of functional interfaces (An interface with single abstract method is called functional interface. An example is java.lang.Runnable). lambda expressions implement the only abstract function and therefore implement functional interfaces.

```
// Java program implements method inside method 
public class GFG { 
interface myInterface { 
    void run(); 
} 

// function have implements another function 
// run() using Lambda expression 
static void Foo() 
{ 
    // Lambda expression 
    myInterface r = () -> 
    { 
        System.out.println("geeksforgeeks"); 
    }; 
    r.run(); 
} 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Foo(); 
} 
}
```